# Oauth2 oauth/token endpoint issue in Spring Boot behind Nginx

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, nginx, lets-encrypt

I am deploying Spring Boot application behind a Nginx proxy server. Whenever I try to authenticate a user using this endpoint `/oauth/token` I don't get any response.

This is my `application.properties`

```
spring.profiles.active=prod
server.port=8088
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header= X-Forwarded-For
server.tomcat.protocol-header= X-Forwarded-Proto

#server.servlet.context-path=/
API.URL=/api/v1
```

And this is the configure method in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapater

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        logger.debug("configure");
        System.out.println("configure ");

        http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                ;

    }
```

And this is my nginx configuration file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myserver.com;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name myserver.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate  /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.com/fullchain.pem;

    location / {
             proxy_pass        http://myserver:8088;
             proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
             proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;  
        }
}
```

I am able to hit other endpoints but not `oauth/token`. I am using Amazon EC2 instance.

When I try to hit the endpoint in Postman I get

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT some_ip_that_is_not_ec2_ip:443
Warning: This request did not get sent completely and might not have all the required system headers
```

And when I try to hit the endpoint using Okhttp I get

```
Server: nginx/1.17.8
    Content-Type: text/html
    Content-Length: 157
    Connection: close
    <html>
    <head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
    <body>
    <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
    <hr><center>nginx/1.17.8</center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue ?